Не получается сделать кластер на Яндекс картах с метками Placemark
Есть такая карта, нужно сделать кластер меток, пробовал разные варианты, но ничего не сработала
Есть особенность, что у меток есть iconContent, может из-за это не работает?
Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать тут кластеры? (меток на самом деле больше, я их просто удалил)
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [44.83, 47.11],
            zoom: 2
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity
 
         }),

myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([12.201181,44.415813], {
            balloonContentHeader: "1",
            balloonContentBody: "Содержимое ",
            balloonContentFooter: "Подвал",
            hintContent: "Хинт метки",
            iconContent: "1"
 });

myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([12.274369,45.702974], {
            balloonContentHeader: "2",
            balloonContentBody: "Содержимое",
            balloonContentFooter: "Подвал",
            hintContent: "Хинт метки",
            iconContent: "2"
 });

myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark([12.274369,45.702974], {
            balloonContentHeader: "2",
            balloonContentBody: "Содержимое",
            balloonContentFooter: "Подвал",
            hintContent: "Хинт метки",
            iconContent: "3"
 });

myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1)
.add(myPlacemark1)
.add(myPlacemark2)
.add(myPlacemark3);


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

В вашем коде нет непосредственно работы с кластеризатором. Посмотрите пример в нашей песочнице. Необходимо добавлять метки не в геообъекты, а в кластеризатор.
var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({});
myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
  
clusterer.add(myPlacemark1)
.add(myPlacemark2)
.add(myPlacemark3);

